# Highcharts, multiple parts chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

What whould be the best approach to do something like ? [image]

I think I need to do 2 charts or can I do it in the same ? I don't know how to separate the 2 parts.
Labels translate by "Late" and "Next". It's 2 different series

Answer (score 1):

One method is to make your "red" series use negative values and your "blue" series use positive values. To make the labels on the xAxis be positive you would make the xAxis label `formatter` use an absolute value of `this.value`.